# Compile boost example programs on AIX

Tags: c++, boost, aix

I can successfully compile the simple_ls.cpp with this command:

```
xlc++  -qstrict -brtl -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib simple_ls.cpp -lboost_filesystem -o simple_ls
```

However when I use the exact same syntax with the path_info.cpp command I get this error:

```
xlc++  -qstrict -brtl -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib path_info.cpp -lboost_filesystem -o path_info
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .boost::system::generic_category()
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .boost::system::system_category()
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the second program with boost_system.

```
xlc++ -qstrict -brtl -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib path_info.cpp -lboost_filesystem -o path_info -lboost_system
```

Comment: @user1720192, where is the result?

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion got many errors:

xlc++ -qstrict -brtl -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib path_info.cpp -lboost_filesystem -o path_info -lboost_system
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy(bool)
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .std::exception::~exception()
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Copy(unsigned long)

Comment: Hmmm, cant help with that. I don't have an AIX system to replicate this. Based on the error you posted in original question, it is straight forward missing `boost_system` to link with compiled object.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the -qstrict and the -brtl and it compiled successfully with this command: xlc++ -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib path_info.cpp -lboost_filesystem -o path_info -lboost_system